# "Write failed" when installing base-devel package on live System rescue cd

Tags: package-management, live-usb

I'm trying to rescue a failing hard drive using **SystemRescueCd booted live** from an USB drive. For this purpose I need to compile *ddrutility*. Since the distribution does not have *make* installed, I need to install *base-devel* package first (running the command as root):

```
pacman --sync --refresh --noconfirm base-devel
```

This, however, fails with a write error:

```
...

installing libmpc...
installing gcc...
error: could not extract /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.3.0/lto1 (Write failed)
error: could not extract /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.3.0/plugin/gengtype (Write failed)
error: could not extract /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.3.0/plugin/include/alloc-pool.h (Write failed)
... (many more errors)

error: problem occurred while installing gcc
Optional dependencies for gcc
    lib32-gcc-libs: for generating code for 32-bit ABI
error: could not commit transaction
error: failed to commit transaction (transaction aborted)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

[Full output here.](https://pastebin.com/0Xvbx0R3)

According to *mount* output, the root is writeable:

```
...
airootfs on / type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/run/archiso/sfs/airootfs,upperdir=/run/archiso
...
```

Curiosly, when I check for existence of one of the files mentioned:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.3.0/plugin/include/alloc-pool.h
```

it does not exist before running the pacman command above, and it exists afterwards, but is filed with zeroes (15427 bytes). So maybe the problem lies somewhere else?

Is there a problem in principle with installing packages on a live system? (I understand all changes will be lost after reboot, that's fine.)

Comment: You should get an error about no space left on the device if you hit the limit,  but how much ram do you have in this machine?

Comment: @Livinglifeback Thank you. The machine has 16GB RAM, but your comment pointed me in correct direction: df shows that there is not much space allocated by default on the root partition. I'm posting an answer with the full solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that by default, even though the root partition is writeable, it has too little free space. This can be fixed before booting:

In GRUB menu:

1. Press 'e' to edit boot options
2. Append `cow_spacesize=3G` after the line that starts with `linux /sysrescd/...`
3. Press F10 to boot.

Then:

4. First, `pacman-key --refresh-keys` might have to be run.
5. `pacman --sync --refresh --noconfirm base-devel` now works without error.

*make* should work now.